# Jenkins java jre installation duplicate

Tags: java, jenkins, directory

I'm using Jenkins as my buildserver. It's installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`
Inside that directory I found a folder called `jre`, which has very similarcontents as my already instaled jre at `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112`.

This feels unnecessary, and takes up 150Mb space, and I have a feeling as if I could just point at the installed location, so Jenkins doesn't need to 'duplicate' the whole jre contents as if it was newly installed.

Is it possible to point to the `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112` location, so Jenkins doesn't need this directory anymore? Or could this 'duplication' be deliberate, because Jenkins requires a different jre version?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the other way around. get rid of the pure *jre* installation an use the jdk (set you "global" `JAVA_HOME` and the `PATH` environment variables to the jdk folder).